# appendChild for <script type="text/template">

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild

I try to appendChild several element (for loop) with javascript but it doesn't work

see: https://jsfiddle.net/9tsop7zw/3/

Or:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var profile = document.getElementById("profileJS");
  console.log(profile)
    for(let i=0; i<5; i++) {
    document.getElementById("appendchild").appendChild(profile);
  }
}
```

```html
<script type="text/template" id="profileJS">
    <div class="content">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="name">Profile Name</div>
    <div class="follower">119k</div>
  </div>
</script>

<div id="appendchild"></div>
```

It's only work with
`document.getElementById("something").innerHTML = document.getElementById("profileJS").innerHTML;`
but I really need to appendChild for make this very clean

(cause with `.innerHTML` solutions I need to create childs before set them to the "profileJS".innerHTML)

tell me if you know some solution ty

Comment: First paragraph of : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild - *If the given child is a reference to an existing node in the document, appendChild() moves it from its current position to the new position.* - think of `appendChild` as `moveToChild` - so you're moving the same element over and over.

Comment: Using a script element to hold a template is a dirty and outdated hack. There is an [element designed for that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template).

Comment: moveToChild doesn't exist

Comment: solved : https://jsfiddle.net/kn6xg2Lb/1/

Comment: *think of* not replace with - instead of "..append..child.." think of it as "..move..to..child.." - ie it *moves* the element.

Comment: @freedomn-m ok ty i undrestand, my problem is solved I just used <template> instead of script